# Remove a element from List of objects based on inner object list value in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, remove-if

How can I remove the element from the list if some inner list attribute value fails to meet the condition.The trick here is that attribute is itself a list and comparison is based on some attribute of that inner list. Please refer the below sample and help out to fill the comment section in code:

**Object :**

```
Class product{
 private String productId;
 private String productName;
 private List<Attribute> attributeList;

    public static class Attribute{
        private Long attributeId;
    }
}
```

**Driver class :**

```
Class Driver{
   List<product> productList = new ArrayList<product>();
   /*
   Remove the object from productList if attributeList doesn't contain attribute with attributeId = x;
*/
}
```

Comment: `productList.removeIf(p -> p.getAttributeList().stream().map(Attribute::getAttributeId) .noneMatch(Predicate.isEqual​(x)));`

Answer (score 5):

What you can do it to stream over original list, and leave only objects which satisfy the condition. It might look something like this:

```
List<Product> filtered = productList.stream()
      .filter( p -> p.attributeList().stream().anyMatch( a -> a.attributeId.equals(x))
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

in this live we are actually checking if nested list contains at least one object with `attributeId = x`
`p.attributeList().stream().anyMatch( a -> a.attributeId.equals(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do a foreach loop and remove the unwanted elements. In "product" class you can insert a "FindInnerAtribute" function to search inside the Attributes list and return true if there is some.

```
List<product> productList = new ArrayList<product>();
for(product p : productList){
    if ( p.FindInnerAttribute(x) ){
        productList.remove(p);
    }
}
```

[How to remove from list](https://www.journaldev.com/31869/java-list-remove-methods-arraylist-remove)

Comment: Calling `remove` on the list while you're iterating over it, is broken. In the best case, you get an exception.